# Train RNN on large string using Estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

We would like to make our estimator predict a word or the next work just like the keyboard in your smartphone does. We would like to train it on some text file.

So we went ahead and looked in the tensorflow API and found

```
estimator = RNNEstimator(
    head=tf.contrib.estimator.regression_head(),
    sequence_feature_columns=[token_emb],
    rnn_cell_fn=rnn_cell_fn)
```

which seems to be a convenient way to create an estimator for an RNN. Now, we are facing problems with the feature columns. We are setting them up like this

```
token_sequence = sequence_categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
    key="text", hash_bucket_size=num_of_categories, dtype=tf.string)
token_emb = embedding_column(categorical_column=token_sequence, 
    dimension=8)
```

where `'text'` is defined in our input function

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"text": features},
    y=labels,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
```

where `features` is just a long list of 40-character sequences sampled from our original text.

### The problems

1. Is it possible to use feature columns on string inputs anyway? The documentation does not really give away much.
2. What to do with the labels? At the moment, we get an error since they are never cast to integers
3. Even when introducing arbitrary integers as labels, we still get an error when calling `estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=100)` which says

   > 'Given type: {}'.format(type(features))) ValueError: features should
   >   be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type:

so we are definitely doing something wrong here. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a short example of passing string word features as SparseTensors to a one-label-per-step classification `Estimator` (i.e. language modeling) in the [StateSavingRnnEstimator unit tests](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5da5e8af4650287c9dcde8869ac1158d79c1415f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/state_saving_rnn_estimator_test.py#L592). That looks like approximately what you're trying to do, with the caveat that the Estimator in question is deprecated; it may make sense to take ideas from it and define your own `model_fn`.